# cairo graphics library: how can I transfer data between two xlib surfaces?

Tags: x11, cairo

I want to use the Cairo graphics library to copy the content of one X11 window to another X11 window. I create two surfaces using `cairo_xlib_surface_create()`. Now I want to copy a region from the source surface (position `xs`, `ys`, size `ws`, `hs`) to a given position on the destination surface (position `xd`, `yd`), where it should also become visible.

How would I accomplish this? Would I go through a Cairo image surface as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290221/3852630? This goes from source X11 surface to image surface; how can I copy back from the image surface to the destination X11 surface? And how do I consider the regions above?

Or is the way to go through `cairo_surface_map_to_image()` where I would map the X11 surfaces to images surfaces? But how to proceed from there, how to I transfer data between the image surfaces?

Or am I abusing Cairo and should better do it directly via X11, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965236/3852630?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo does not care what kind of surfaces you have. The following function should copy a rectangular area between two `cairo_surface_t`s. Variable names should be just as in your question.

```c
// Untested, treat this as pseudo-code
void copy_some_area(cairo_surface_t* source, int xs, int ys, int ws, int hs,
                    cairo_surface_t* target, int xd, int yd) {
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create (target);
    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, source, xd - xs, yd - ys);
    cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_rectangle (cr, xd, yd, ws, hs);
    cairo_fill (cr);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
}
```

This function:

- creates a cairo context
- uses the source surface as the source for the context so that the offset between the two surfaces is as wanted (`cairo_set_source_surface` gets the coordinates where the top left corner of the surface should appear).
- tells cairo to "just copy" without any alpha blending or stuff
- informs cairo about the rectangle that should be filled
- fills the rectangle
- cleans up by destroying the context again

> where it should also become visible.

Uhm, perhaps you also want a call to `cairo_surface_flush(target);` to make really, really, *really* sure that cairo actually did the drawing and did not just remember it for later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code compiles out-of-the-box, but when I use my window as destination surface and the root window as source surface, it gives this error message: `X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)` with `Major opcode of failed request:  62 (X_CopyArea)`. I can't really figure out which line causes the error, the message appears after the function is finished.

Comment: ... may be a problem with the root window, if I specify the same window as source, it doesn't crash.

Comment: ... from one window to the same window it has the desired function! Any idea why it doesn't work with the root window?

Comment: A drawable is either a Pixmap or a Window. Put differently. Both Pixmaps or Windows are drawables. BadDrawable means that a Drawable parameter was invalid. Are you sure you are creating a cairo surface for the root window correctly? It seems like one of the window IDs here is off and you say the destination window is fine.

Comment: From https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#errors, BadDrawable means `A value for a DRAWABLE argument does not name a defined WINDOW or PIXMAP.`

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right: I forgot to get the root window using `DefaultRootWindow()`, the variable I used was undefined. Now it also copies from the root window.

Comment: I didn't try it yet: would the copying via Cairo surfaces also work if the windows associated with the surfaces have different `depth` (e.g. 24 vs. 32)? This is problematic if it is done directly in X11.

Comment: Yup, cairo manages that. You just have to tell cairo about the correct visual when calling `cairo_xlib_surface_create`.